# Call a getter of Class1 from Class2

Tags: java, call, getter

I have a very basic question regarding object-oriented programming.

There are two classes - Class1 and Class2. I need to call a getter of Class1 from Class2 (please see the code). The problem is that the below-presented code cannot be compiled. How to change this code to be able to call a getter of Class1 from Class2. So, what is the correct way to tackle this issue?

P.S. If I make the function `getVar1` as a static, the compiler says that `return this.var1` is not correct.

```
public class Class1 
{
    private int var1;

    public Class1(int index1, int index2) 
    {
      //...
      Class2 c2 = new Class2();
      //..
    }

    public int getVar1()
    {
      return this.var1;
    }
}


import Class1;

public Class2
{
    public Class2() 
    {
      //...
      int var = Class1.getVar1(); // !!!
    }
}
```

Comment: If u make the function getVar1 static, you also need to make var1 static. Since you cannot access non-static variable from static context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `public Class2` should be `public class Class2`

secondly, if you change `getVar1` to static you must also change `var1` to static (the reason is that you cannot directly access a non-static member from a static function)

otherwise create an instance of `Class1` and call `getVar1()` on that instance

Answer (score 1):

- To call the method of `Class1` **without static** you need instance of that class.

> If I make the function getVar1 as a static, the compiler says that
>   return this.var1 is not correct.

Rightly because `var1` is *not static*. You would be getting error like:

> Cannot access non-static method in a static context

which should give you the hint.

```
class Class2{
   //pass the instance of Class1 to Class2
   public Class2(Class1 class1){
      class1.getVar1(); //invoke method here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Class1().getVar1();
```

you did not created instance.Create instance before using instance variables or methods.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are looking for. But for time being I made changes.

```
public class Class1 {
    private int var1;

    public Class1() {
    }

    public Class1(int index1, int index2) {
        // ...
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        // ..
    }

    public int getVar1() {
        return this.var1;
    }
}

import Class1;
public class Class2 {
    public Class2() {
        // ...
        int var = new Class1().getVar1(); // !!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Class1` is not **static**, so you can access its variable and functions only by creating instance to it.

```
int var = new Class1.getVar();
```

or make `class1`, `getVar1` and `var1` as **static**

```
public static class1 {
    private static int var1;

    public Class1(int index1, int index2)  {
        //...
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        //..
    }

    public static int getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }
}
```